# Camera settings for extreme close ups

Tags: camera-settings, led-lighting

I am brand new to photography and working with cameras so I am open to any suggestions. I am wondering what settings should I be focusing on for extreme close up shooting to get the best quality images.

My object will be back lit with a single LED and the camera and lens will be within a centimetre of the object.

The camera I am working with is a small board camera which allows me to adjust contrast, gain, gamma, sharpness, exposure, brightness, saturation, and maybe a few other things once I code them in. I would rather not spend days on trail and error figuring out how I want these set so I am hopping to get a starting point from you guys.

Something like which of these settings should be high, which should be low, and which don't really matter in this use case so I can leave them at default.

Thanks

Comment: You are looking for macro. If your camera cannot do macro (cannot focus so close) you have to look for another one. If you have DSLR or mirrorless you can look for macro lenses or for macro rings. The first one allows you to focus in short distances (centimetres), the second one allows you to mount the lens inside-out and focus.

Comment: I am not using anything remotely like a DSLR, or mirrorless. I have a CMOS sensor on a board with a series of custom lenses placed in front of it, that allows me to put the camera right beside my object. I was more interested in the actual settings of the camera.

Comment: Then put the sensor further from your lenses. And keep it all light-tight

Comment: I think most of the settings you mentioned are done in post processing. You mostly need to get it in focus and exposed without saturation. So exposure and gain.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t know what a “board” camera is! I am assuming it is a miniature video camera of the type used in laptop computers. Miniature cameras are fitted, by necessity with short focal length lenses.  Such a lash-up delivers an expanded subject distance range without the necessary to adjust focus (extreme depth of field). Will it focus on a subject 10mm from the front of the lens? I do not know but: I know you can impose a lens ahead of the camera lens that will allow close focusing. A 10mm lens mounted before your camera lens will do this deed.

Light rays from your nearby subject are diverging (spreading out). The camera lens must admit these rays and cause them to diverge. Inside the camera, these rays trace out the shape of a cone of light. The vertex must just kiss the surface of the imaging chip. Likely the camera lens of your “board” camera lacks sufficient converging strength thus it will not focus on an object 10mm from the front of the lens. A positive 10mm lens ahead of your camera lens will cause the diverging rays from an object 10mm  to enter the camera lens as parallel rays.  This lash-up fools the “board” camera. It sees the 10mm distant subject as if it were at a far distance.

Go to Edmund Scientific and purchase a 10mm focal length achromatic lens with sufficient diameter to cover your camera lens. Such a lens will be inexpensive. You can experiment by imposing a hand-held magnifying glass before your camera. Most you find around the house will be constructed using only one lens.  These will work but, likely you will find you can’t achieve the desired 10mm subject distance as household magnifier is not that powerful. Also, a single glass lens magnifier will induce color fringing. An achromatic lens is a sandwich of two lenses that together mitigate this error called chromatic aberration. 
Best of luck:
https://www.edmundoptics.com/search/#stq=10mm+achromatic&stp=1

Comment: You are correct about the board cameras [link](https://www.e-consystems.com/ar0330-lowlight-cameramodule.asp) Great answer though, thanks. Is placing these additional lenses in front of my original lens the only/most realistic option or is it possible to get a M12 lens with a high enough converging strength

Comment: What I know about the M12 is a thimble full -- compared to the Pacific Ocean. What I do know, mounting a supplemental lens ahead of your camera lens has few downsides. We humans use reading glasses and that's the principle you will be using if you follow my advise. The lens already mounted will work if you can somehow move it forward.  We are talking detaching and spacing it several millimeters more forward. We do this all the time with our cameras. The technique is called adding tubes or rings. These are spacers that remount the lens more forward of its normal position.